# How to Include Fields in Query String When Making Request of WordPress.org Plugin API?

Tags: plugins, api, query-string

I am running a query against the WordPress.org Plugin API that looks like this went built:

> https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&request[per_page]=10&request[browse]=popular&request[page]=1

This works great. Now I want to reduce the amount of data that is being returned in each request by passing in fields that shouldn't be displayed like so:

> https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&request[per_page]=10&request[browse]=popular&request[fields][description]=false&request[page]=1

Problem is, this doesn't work. I still get back the description field. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this is border line on topic. A better place to ask is probably the relevant slack channel

Comment: @MarkKaplun - I'm not familiar with the relevant slack channel. Can you direct me?

Comment: in the wordpress.org slack (you will have to have a wordpress.org user IIRC) just ask on the main channel where to ask wordpress.org API questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HT to otto42 on the WordPress Slack who pointed out that false might be evaluating as true and to instead try using 0...which I did and it worked:

https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&request[per_page]=10&request[browse]=popular&request[fields][description]=0&request[page]=1